# multi line context menu - android

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

On long press of item in list view, am opening the context menu. The problem the string present in context menu is bit lengthy. it is getting truncated. Is there a way to show the multiple lines string in context menu.

I checked the `list_menu_item_layout.xml` in which text view contains `android:singleLine="false"`.

Is there a way to change this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the set the android:inputType="textMultiLine"
Hope this can help you.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no public methods exposed to set the flag.